# Skip/Ignore/Bypass empty Text boxes while calculating in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a simple marks grading system using vb.net in visual studio 2013. This is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    If TextBox1.Text >= 0 And TextBox1.Text <= 50 Then
        TextBox4.Text = 1
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text >= 51 And TextBox1.Text <= 100 Then
        TextBox4.Text = 0
    End If



    If TextBox2.Text >= 0 And TextBox2.Text <= 50 Then
        TextBox5.Text = 1
    End If

    If TextBox2.Text >= 51 And TextBox2.Text <= 100 Then
        TextBox5.Text = 0
    End If



    If TextBox3.Text >= 0 And TextBox3.Text <= 50 Then
        TextBox6.Text = 1
    End If

    If TextBox3.Text >= 51 And TextBox3.Text <= 100 Then
        TextBox6.Text = 0
    End If


    TextBox7.Text = Int(TextBox1.Text) + Int(TextBox2.Text) + Int(TextBox3.Text)

End Sub
```

In this, while calculating if there is any empty text box, then code doesn't work and gives errors.

I used this code to bypass empty text box.

```
If Textbox1.Text = ""
   Textbox1.Text = 0 'or 30
End If
```

but while calculating the grades this empty data include to 0-50 by software. Therefore it gives a wrong result. It is useless to apply numbers to empty text-boxes.

Kindly tell me how to skip/ignore or bypass empty text-boxes while calculating?

Comment: Don't do anything unless the TextBox.Text.Length property is larger than 0.  Further improve the code and prevent unexpected FormatException crashes by using Integer.TryParse().  Putting `Option Strict On` at the top of the source code file always helps you discover this by yourself.

Comment: as a beginner, I don't   know how to use the TryParse(). Kindly tell me how to do it please ! (i expect the the code which rebuilt from my code.)

Comment: Looking at the code samples in the MSDN library is by far the best way to stop being a beginner.  [Start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Comment: dear  Hans Passant, anyway i would like to thanks you to direct me to other source. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little more if's and you're there - I have added a function to your code as it looks like all three boxes require the same criteria? If not you'd have to specify each one separately.

Hopefully this makes sense. It uses a determination to see whether the textbox is actually valid, also checks if is numeric and then after if the number is valid.

Have a go with this let us know if its good!

Hth Chicken

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim t1 As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim t2 As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim t3 As String = TextBox3.Text

    Dim a1 As Integer = Get_result(t1)
    Dim a2 As Integer = Get_result(t2)
    Dim a3 As Integer = Get_result(t3)

    TextBox4.Text = a1
    TextBox5.Text = a2
    TextBox6.Text = a3

    Dim Sumed As Integer = 0
    'If -1 then we dont use this number...
    If Not a1 = -1 Then Sumed += a1
    If Not a2 = -1 Then Sumed += a2
    If Not a3 = -1 Then Sumed += a3

    TextBox7.Text = Sumed

End Sub

Function Get_result(t As String) As Integer
    'Returns -1 if this isnt a valid answer, or blank etc...
    If t.Length = 0 Then Return -1
    If Not IsNumeric(t) Then Return -1
    Select Case CInt(t)
        Case Is < 0
            Return -1

        Case Is < 51
            Return 1

        Case Is < 101
            Return 0

        Case Else
            Return -1
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a million for quick response dear. I will try and tell you the result.Thanks

Comment: Dear Chicken, Your code is perfect and works fine for me. Thanks a million!. i cant believe how to expertise in coding as you.

Comment: You're you kind!!! ;) that's what we're here for! If you could mark as answered that'd be perfect cheers!

Comment: another question- in my application button1 click event is    Textbox1.clear   Textbox2.clear    Textbox3.clear    Textbox4.clear   Textbox5.clear    Textbox6.clear    Textbox7.clear   As this repeating is a little headache. how to accumulate these into single code? please tell me!

Comment: Quick answer :) - you can add handles using separated by a comma like this `Private Sub Button1_click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CB_1.Click, CB_2.Click, CB_3.Click` you can add as many handles as you like, so for you buttons 1 to 7. My example handles buttons (CB_1, CB_2 and CB_3), although you can add handles easily if you wanted say textbox.leave with button.click as they have different event arguments.